# Angular directive for multi level menu

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this menu stucture and i want to create a directive in angular that make lists recursively.

```
    $scope.Items = [
     {
      title: 'Spaces',
      icon: 'icon-layers',
      href: 'javascript:;',
      isActive: path === '/Spaces',
      subitems: 
       [{
        title: 'OpenSpaces',
        icon: 'icon-layers',
        href: '#/OpenSpaces',
        isActive: path === '/OpenSpaces',
        subitems: 
          [{
            title: 'OpenSpaces2',
            icon: 'icon-layers',
            href: '#/OpenSpaces2',
            isActive: path === '/OpenSpaces2',
          }]
       }]
     }, 
     {
      title: 'Meeting',
      icon: 'icon-layers',
      href: '#/meeting',
      isActive: path === '/meeting'
     }];
```

I've created a function that generate the correct html .How i can associate this function into a directive? So i can write into html the directive tag.

This is the function :

```
   angular.forEach(dashitems, function(value, key) {
            $scope.menu+="<li class='nav-item'>";
            if(value.hasOwnProperty('subitems')){


               $scope.menu+="<a href='javascript:;' class='nav-link nav-toggle'>"+
                  "<i class='"+value.icon+"'></i>"+
                  "<span class='title'>"+value.title+"</span>"+
                  '<span class="arrow open"></span>'+
                   "</a>";
               $scope.menu += '<ul class="sub-menu">';
              printList(value.subitems);
               $scope.menu += "</ul>";
            }else{
                 $scope.menu+=' <a href="'+value.href+'" >'+
                          '<i class="'+value.icon+'"></i>'+
                          '<span class="title">'+value.title+'</span>'+
                      '</a>';                  
            }
            $scope.menu+="</li>";
        });



        return $scope.menu;
    }
```

Any suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: Looks like a tree structure. This may be helpful:  https://github.com/wix/angular-tree-control

Comment: Do you want the list to be rendered as `ul` `li`s eventually, or alternatively would you want each element to have its own different _tags_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
angular
  .module('App').directive('menuBar', function() {
    return {
  replace: true,
  restrict: 'E',
  controller: ['$scope','$location',function ($scope,$location) {

     //function
   }],
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

           elem.append("<ul>"+scope.printList(scope.dashitems)+"</ul>");
        }
  }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that you've mistaken "ul"s and "li"s in your code (correct me if not) and i changed them.

aside from that, i'm not quite sure what did you mean by this part:

```
    $scope.menu += '<ul class="sub-menu">';
    printList(value.subitems);
    $scope.menu += "</ul>";
```

but if you want to repeat "ul"s and inside them, repeat some "li"s, why can't you use ng-repeat?

i think it would go something like this(i copied most parts from your code):

```
<ul ng-repat="item in Items" class='nav-item'>
    <a href='javascript:;' class='nav-link nav-toggle'>
        <i class="{{item.icon}}"></i>
        <span class='title'>{{item.title}}</span>
        <span class="arrow open"></span>
    </a>
    <li class="sub-menu" ng-if="item.subitems" ng-repeat="subs in item.subitems">
        //some data using subs.title and other stuff...
    </li>
</ul>
```

i think even the ng-if wouldn't be necessary.
anyhow, you are able to nest ng-repeats inside each other if that's what you want...

hope that's helpfull

Comment: I can't use ng-repeat because it's not recursively( u don't know how many levels )

Answer (score 0):

[***This***](https://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/6rpxetfs/) is how I would prefer to go about your problem.

I'd suggest you create a service which accepts a *blueprint* object to generate the *raw* html - which in turn incorporates a custom directive.

### Custom Directive

Here is a possible approach to defining a directive for each list item; note that to the scope object of the directive definition, you are passing the required information such as the `title`, `href`, and the `icon` of the list item:

```
app.directive('navItem', function() {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  transclude: true,
  replace: true,
  scope: {
      title: '@',
      href: '@',
      icon: '@'
    },
  template: '<li><a href="{{ href }}">'
   + '<i class="{{ icon }}"></i><span>{{ title }}</span></a>'
   + '<ul class="sub-menu" ng-transclude></ul></li>'
  };
});
```

### Service for Directive Generation

A service for *recursively* creating HTML nodes that would be later compiled into their directive definitions:

```
app.service('NavBarCreator', [function() {
var rawHtml = angular.element("<div />");

return function(itemJson) {
  recur(itemJson, rawHtml);
  return rawHtml.html();
};

function recur(items, parent) {
  angular.forEach(items, function(item, i) {
    //create the directive HTML node with the passed in attributes to be used in the `scope` object of the directive
    var itemHtml = angular.element('<nav-item />');

     itemHtml.attr('title', item.title);
     itemHtml.attr('href', item.href);
     itemHtml.attr('icon', item.icon);

      parent.append(itemHtml);
      //repeat the same if the item has any subitems
      if (item.subitems && item.subitems.length > 0) {
        recur(item.subitems, itemHtml);
      }
    })
  };
}]);
```

***Note:***

I've also implemented a *wrapper* directive which implements the above service and is responsible for consuming the *blueprint* JSON for the menu items, as well as `$compiling` its content, so that the directive definition - defined earlier - for its sub-items is fired.

This is totally optional, as you can apply the same logic in your controller. However, it may contribute into keeping things cleaner a bit.